# Facebook like button change from external url to facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website with a Facebook Like button on the homepage.
The Like button URL is www.domain.com.
I have a bunch of users who liked my URL.

After some time, I created a Facebook Page for my website and changed the destination of the Like button to the URL of the Facebook Page.

Is it possible to connect the website to the Facebook page ?
Is it possible to move the likes from website to page?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to have separate counters then the answer is no - you can not "move" likes from one url to another.

I do however recommend contacting facebook and trying to resolve this issue with them.